# Stop Consuming messages from 00:00 - 01:00 RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, rabbitmq

I Have implemented RabbitMQ on my Payments Service Of MFO, currently we need to stop consuming messages from 00:00 to 01:00. we need to be published messages but not to consume untill 1 o'clock, because it is time our SQL Job of CloseDay  needs, so if we receive payment during 00:00-01:00 we want it to be waited in queue and then consumed after 01:00, is there any configuration I can use to configure queue? service is written on .NET Core

Comment: Never heard about such a setting. My guess is you want to 100% terminate the consumer in that period. At least I would think that is more elegant than some kind of check in the Received event